# Deploy API Platform (Symfony) App on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: php, symfony, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, api-platform.com

I'm trying to deploy my PHP app made with the API Platform bundle on Google Cloud Platform.

First, I tried to do it via Google Cloud SDK Shell.
I've created a app.yaml file and a Dockerfile :

app.yaml

```
# runtime: php
# env: flex

# env_variables:
  # APP_ENV: 'prod'
  # DOCUMENT_ROOT: '/app/public'
  
  # Use the PHP 7.4 runtime
runtime: php74

# Defaults to "serve index.php" 
entrypoint: serve public/index.php

# If your main page is index.php, comment the above entrypoint setting
```

Dockerfile

```
# Use the official PHP image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/php
FROM php:8.0-apache

# Configure PHP for Cloud Run.
# Precompile PHP code with opcache.
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j "$(nproc)" opcache
RUN set -ex; \
  { \
    echo "; Cloud Run enforces memory & timeouts"; \
    echo "memory_limit = -1"; \
    echo "max_execution_time = 0"; \
    echo "; File upload at Cloud Run network limit"; \
    echo "upload_max_filesize = 32M"; \
    echo "post_max_size = 32M"; \
    echo "; Configure Opcache for Containers"; \
    echo "opcache.enable = On"; \
    echo "opcache.validate_timestamps = Off"; \
    echo "; Configure Opcache Memory (Application-specific)"; \
    echo "opcache.memory_consumption = 32"; \
  } > "$PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/cloud-run.ini"

# Copy in custom code from the host machine.
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . ./

# Use the PORT environment variable in Apache configuration files.
# https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#port
RUN sed -i 's/80/${PORT}/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf

# Configure PHP for development.
# Switch to the production php.ini for production operations.
# RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
# https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/php/README.md#configuration
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
```

Then I run `gcloud deploy app` in my project folder.
I then get the API platform project online but not any ref is working. It gives a 404 error.

Here is my screen :
[image: screenshot apiplatform]

So, I tried to follow the explanation here to deploy an API platform project on Googl Cloud (Kubernetes) :
https://api-platform.com/docs/deployment/kubernetes/

but when I run (and I replace the test-api-platform by my project ID)

```
docker build -t gcr.io/test-api-platform/php:0.1.0 -t gcr.io/test-api-platform/php:latest api --target api_platform_php
docker build -t gcr.io/test-api-platform/caddy:0.1.0 -t gcr.io/test-api-platform/caddy:latest api --target api_platform_caddy
docker build -t gcr.io/test-api-platform/pwa:0.1.0 -t gcr.io/test-api-platform/pwa:latest pwa --target api_platform_pwa_prod
```

I get : `unable to prepare context: path "api" not found`

Can somebody help me please ?

Comment: You are mixing deployment configurations for different services together which will not work. Review the docs to see how an App Engine Flexible application is built and deployed: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/create-app

Comment: Yes indeed but if I compare with the example you sent, I'm doing the same. 
I have my app.yaml file and run gcloud app build from my project's folder. Isn't it the same ?

Comment: No, it is not the same. Your app.yaml is not even complete. What do you expect to do with the Dockerfile? You have tagged Kubernetes but are deploying on App Engine Flexible.  You are mixing deployment configurations for different services together and that will not work.